# pbft implementation in python when f=1

Tags: python, algorithm, blockchain, consensus

I want to implement pbft algorithm(3f+1 systems;f=1) in python. But what is the channel should use for sending and receiving from replicas. I have tried python multicast but it seems something going wrong while receiving. So please suggest any solution that can put me forward. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **authenticated point-to-point communication channel** to implement any sorts of BFT algorithm. Because PBFT assumes all participant's identity are established in prior, you don't need to assume multicast communication primitive. Even though broadcast is executed in PBFT protocol, each message is encrypted by its private key. So you don't need to use multicast or broadcast.